# laravel decode pagination links

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel's Pagination.
On visiting this URL: `/refrigerators?type=single-door,double-door&capacity=215l,400l,333l` I'm loading the filtered products and paginate filtered products using:
`$products->appends(request()->input());`

So it generates links with encoded commas, replacing them with `%2C`.
Example: `/refrigerators?type=single-door%2Cdouble-door&capacity=215l%2C400l%2C333l&page=2`
Is there any way to decode the pagination links using `{{$products->links()}}`?

Why I want to do so?

1. Links looks nice and readable.
2. Javascript code breaks when URL is encoded.

Comment: please read the doc you can pass extra param to pagination https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: @KamleshPaul the issue with not with passing parameters, i'm already passing them with `$products->appends(request()->input())` but the final rendered parameters are urlencoded, i'm looking to decode them.

Comment: Can you provide the javascript error, where the encoded URL "breaks" your code? What about doing `decodeURIComponent('/refrigerators?type=single-door%2Cdouble-door&capacity=215l%2C400l%2C333l&page=2')` in JavaScript?

Comment: @shaedrich It works fine actually `decodeURIComponent(window.location.search)`, but then again URL looks ugly while paginating.

Comment: You can also do `{{urldecode($products->links())}}` in your blade view. But keep in mind that the URL is encoded for a reason and might break your view.